# WSO2 Enterprise Integrator (6.5.0) Security, Access-Control

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm using WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 6.5.0 (last-release).

We need to put some access control to our vendors

Let's say there are three vendor company that connect to our services.

Things that i wanted to do are :

- I wanna put restrict or access control to these vendor companies
- Only first company can access to this URL (SOAP or REST services) and others can connect to each URL that they can access

Does WSO2 EI have this kind of feature? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may try out the [Throttle Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Throttle+Mediator) for this purpose. In where you may define throttle policies to restrict the access to a service ( URL ) based on IP addresses or domains.

[Here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Sample+371%3A+Restricting+Requests+Based+on+Policies)  , you may find an example policy to throttle based on IP addresses.

Comment: Thank you Nirothipan for reply, i will put my eyes on it